# Setting keyboard shortcut for a character in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Is there any way I can set a shortcut for a character like equal sign (`=`) in WebStorm?

For example: <kbd>Cmd + J</kbd> prints `=`

In VSCode we can make a snippet and set a shortcut for that but I could not find any way in WebStorm.

Comment: Record a macro ?

Comment: @LazyOne Worked, was not familiar with macros. put it on an answere if you want. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Macros functionality for such thing: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html

1. Make sure that the focus is in the Editor area
2. Use `Edit | Macros | Start Macro Recording`
3. Press `=`
4. Now stop recording, `Edit | Macros | Stop Macro Recording`
5. Give it a name
6. Go to `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`, locate your freshly recorded macro there (will be under the `Macros` node) and assign any desired shortcut for that